# Socket.io adaptor for hubot

Tags: hubot, socket.io-1.0

I have recently started writing hubot coffee script.

I would like to know if there is any adaptor which can integrate hubot with socket.io chat framework.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check those? They are not very recent but they may fit your need.

- https://github.com/andreapavoni/hubot-socket.io-adapter
- https://github.com/creatorrr/hubot.io

I'm not sure if they work, but maybe they can provide good code example if you want to make your own.